# ArcPy Layer won't save to variable in same .py file after Kernel Density creation

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm running a python script in ArcGIS where I create a kernel density layer. In the next steps I want to run scripts to change the symbology, but it keeps failing either by not saving to the the variable I name it to or when I just try to run it straight to that lyr using the below.
Using ArcGIS 10.8.1

```
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if lyr.name == 'kd':
        lyr.symbology.numClasses = 4
        excval = lyr.symbology.classBreakValues[1]
        lyr.symbology.excludedValues = '0 - ' + str(excval)
```

However, when I run these in a separate .py file or by typing in manually, it works perfectly.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)